How to create a whitelist with two fields in KQL with a Watchlist?
I need to make a query that checks if an event doesn't match two fields from a watchlist.
Context: I have a watchlist with two fields, one is a user email and other is a country code, this allows me to ignore events from users who are in an specific country and I don't need to see.
I know how to validate watchlists with one single field:
| where Username !in (_GetWatchlist("query_WL")|project Username)

I am translating queries from Splunk, but this logic doesn't work at all:
Splunk:
| search NOT  [ | inputlookup query_WL.csv | fields Username CountryCode]

KQL
| where Username !in (_GetWatchlist("query_WL")|project Username) and CountryCode !in (_GetWatchlist("query_WL")|project CountryCode)

This is blowing my mind, I don't know how to do the same in KQL.

Your query looks ok, except that you write project CountyCode at the end instead of project CountryCode I guess. What is not working exactly?

Well, it was a typo just writing it here. The problem is that my query is not checking both fields together.
For example, I have a user named "john" that is allowed to connect from "FR".
My query is removing all events from "john" from all countries and all events from "FR" from all users but I need to remove just events where both fields are true in one event.

You could anti-join the fields UserName and CountryCode:
let Blacklist = datatable(
    UserName: string,
    CountryCode: string
)
    [
    "John", "DE",
    "John", "US"
];
let Data = datatable(
    UserName: string,
    CountryCode: string
)
    [
    "John", "DE",
    "John", "US",
    "Mat", "DE",
    "William", "UK",
];
Data
| join kind = anti(Blacklist) on UserName, CountryCode

Result:

Find sample Code here.

There is also a shorter version without the "strcat" possible:
Data | join kind = anti Blacklist on UserName, CountryCode

This is perfect! I guess that "join" was the correct way but I didn't know what mode to use. Thank you!
